# How to change the stdin and stdout encoding on Python 2

Tags: encoding, stdout, stdin, python-2.x

I'm using Windows and Linux machines for the same project. The default encoding for stdin on Windows is cp1252, and on Linux it is utf-8.

I would like to change everything to utf-8.
Is it possible? How can I do it?

This question is about Python 2; for Python 3, see [Python 3: How to specify stdin encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549332/python-3-how-to-specify-stdin-encoding)

Answer (score 19):

You can do this by not relying on the implicit encoding when printing things. Not relying on that is a good idea in any case -- the implicit encoding is only used when printing to stdout and when stdout is connected to a terminal.

A better approach is to use `unicode` everywhere, and use `codecs.open` or `codecs.getwriter` everywhere. You wrap `sys.stdout` in an object that automatically encodes your unicode strings into UTF-8 using, for example:

```
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
```

This will only work if you use unicode everywhere, though. So, use unicode everywhere. Really, everywhere.

Comment: stdin isn't decoded automatically, so you always have to do this yourself. And assuming the input is UTF-8 is probably a bad idea, but there's `codecs.getreader('utf-8')(sys.stdin)` if you really want to.

Comment: Note that in contrast to Python 2, Python 3 actually automatically decodes stdin: http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin -- this behavior can be changed as outlined in the docs.

Comment: Is there any way in Python 3 to forcibly change the encoding of STDIN regardless of the environment variables?

Comment: In Python 3.8 `codecs.getreader('utf-8')(sys.stdin)` does not work. Use `codecs.getreader('utf-8')(sys.stdin.buffer)` and `codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout.buffer)` instead.

Answer (score 18):

This is an old question, but just for reference.

To read `UTF-8` from `stdin`, use:

```
UTF8Reader = codecs.getreader('utf8')
sys.stdin = UTF8Reader(sys.stdin)

# Then, e.g.:
for _ in sys.stdin:
    print _.strip()
```

To write `UTF-8` to `stdout`, use:

```
UTF8Writer = codecs.getwriter('utf8')
sys.stdout = UTF8Writer(sys.stdout)

# Then, e.g.:
print 'Anything'
```

Comment: In Python 3.8 `codecs.getreader('utf-8')(sys.stdin)` (equivalent to this post) does not work. Use `codecs.getreader('utf-8')(sys.stdin.buffer)` and `codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout.buffer)` instead.

Answer (score 10):

Python automatically detects the encoding of stdin. The simplest way I have found to specify an encoding when automatic detection isn't working properly is to use the [PYTHONIOENCODING](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) environment variable, as in the following example:

```
pipeline | PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8" /path/to/your-script.py
```

For more information about encoding detection and this variable on different platforms you can look at the [sys.stdin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

A simple code snippet I used, which works for me on ubuntu: python2.7 and python3.6

```py
from sys import version_info
if version_info.major == 2:  # for python2
    import codecs
    # for stdin
    UTF8Reader = codecs.getreader('utf8')
    sys.stdin = UTF8Reader(sys.stdin)
    # for stdout
    UTF8Writer = codecs.getwriter('utf8')
    sys.stdout = UTF8Writer(sys.stdout)
elif version_info.major == 3:  # for python3
    import codecs
    # for stdin
    UTF8Reader = codecs.getreader('utf8')
    sys.stdin = UTF8Reader(sys.stdin.buffer)
    # for stdout
    UTF8Writer = codecs.getwriter('utf8')
    sys.stdout = UTF8Writer(sys.stdout.buffer)
```