# Python unicode problem

Tags: python, unicode, file-io

I'm receiving some data from a ZODB (Zope Object Database). I receive a `mybrains` object. Then I do:

```
o = mybrains.getObject()
```

and I receive a "Person" object in my project. Then, I can do

```
b = o.name
```

and doing `print b` on my class I get:

```
José Carlos
```

and `print b.name.__class__`

```
<type 'unicode'>
```

I have a lot of "Person" objects. They are added to a list.

```
names = [o.nome, o1.nome, o2.nome]
```

Then, I trying to create a text file with this data.

```
delimiter = ';'
all = delimiter.join(names) + '\n'
```

No problem. Now, when I do a `print all` I have:

```
José Carlos;Jonas;Natália
Juan;John
```

But when I try to create a file of it:

```
f = open("/tmp/test.txt", "w")
f.write(all)
```

I get an error like this (the positions aren't exaclty the same, since I change the names)

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 84: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I can print already with the "correct" form to display it, why I can't write a file with it? Which encode/decode method should I use to write a file with this data?

I'm using Python 2.4.5 (can't upgrade it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UnicodeEncodeError: **'ascii'** codec

`write` is trying to encode the string using the ascii codec (which doesn't have a way of encoding accented characters like é or à.

Instead use

```
import codecs
with codecs.open("/tmp/test.txt",'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:   
    f.write(all.decode('utf-8'))
```

or choose some other codec (like cp1252) which can encode the characters in your string.

PS. `all.decode('utf-8')` was used above because `f.write` expects a unicode string. [Better than using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737966/how-to-change-the-stdin-encoding-on-python/2738005#2738005) `all.decode('utf-8')` would be to convert all your strings to unicode early, work in unicode, and encode to a specific encoding like 'utf-8' late -- only when you have to.

PPS. It looks like `names` might already be a list of unicode strings. In that case, define `delimiter` to be a unicode string too: `delimiter = u';'`, so `all` will be a unicode string. Then

```
with codecs.open("/tmp/test.txt",'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:   
    f.write(all)
```

should work (unless there is some issue with Python 2.4 that I'm not aware of.)

If 'utf-8' does not work, remember to try other encodings that contain the characters you need, and that your computer knows about. On Windows, that might mean 'cp1252'.

Comment: Is the with statement available in Python 2.4?

Comment: @Somebody: Unfortunately, no. It was implemented in Python 2.5. If you are using Python 2.4, you have no choice but to use `f = open("/tmp/test.txt", "w")`.

Comment: How do I convert all my strings to unicode early, If I receive it from a method I don't have control? I already receive a "José Carlos" in a variable, not a string literal. When I try to do unicode(all, "utf-8") I get "TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported"...

Comment: I was just trying to describe my setup, thanks for your "convert all strings before suggestion"...

Comment: @unutbu: I don't know if I didt something wrong before, but adding u' do the delimiter and to the \n's, and removing .decode from all, it worked. I opened my file after the "exporting", and it worked. Thanks for your help. I'm still not expert at this subject, but your explanation about this issues can be a start. I learned a lot from this resource http://www.red-mercury.com/blog/eclectic-tech/python-unicode-fixing-utf-8-encoded-as-latin-1-iso-8859-1/ as well.

Answer (score 0):

You told Python to print `all`, but since `all` has no fixed computer representation, Python first had to convert `all` to some printable form. Since you didn't tell Python how to do the conversion, it assumed you wanted ASCII. Unfortunately, ASCII can only handle values from 0 to 127, and `all` contains values out of that range, hence you see an error.

To fix this use:

```
all = "José Carlos;Jonas;Natália Juan;John"
import codecs
f = codecs.open("/tmp/test.txt", "w", "utf-8")
f.write(all.decode("utf-8"))
f.close()
```

Comment: This doesnt work... UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I added the call to decode and then cut and pasted my code into Python 2.5, in interactive mode, running on my Mac (Mac OS X 10.5.8). It worked perfectly. Are you still having problems? Even if you call decode first?

Comment: The OP started with a Unicode string, so 'all' above should be 'all=u"..."'.  Then just 'f.write(all)' and the codec will *encode* the Unicode string to the file.

Comment: -1 for TWO reasons (1) read Mark's comment (2) your `all` is a str object encoded in who-knows-what encoding; 'utf8' on yours, cp850 in a Western-European-language Windows system, ... copy/paste into the (Command Prompt) interactive interpreter on my box dies in the utf8 decode; it's an *accident* that  the OP is on a *x platform and thus the standard encoding is presumably utf8.