# Python 3: How to specify stdin encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encoding, stdin

While porting code from Python 2 to Python 3, I run into this problem when reading UTF-8 text from standard input. In Python 2, this works fine:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    ...
```

But Python 3 expects ASCII from *sys.stdin*, and if there are non-ASCII characters in the input, I get the error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte .. in position ..: ordinal not in range(128)

For a regular file, I would specify the encoding when opening the file:

```
with open('filename', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        ...
```

But how can I specify the encoding for standard input? Other SO posts (e.g. [How to change the stdin encoding on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737966/how-to-change-the-stdin-encoding-on-python)) have suggested using

```
input_stream = codecs.getreader('utf-8')(sys.stdin)
for line in input_stream:
    ...
```

However, this doesn't work in Python 3. I still get the same error message. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.2 and my locale is set to en_US.UTF-8.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger Given that Python 2 and Python 3 have very different answers here, these aren't duplicate questions. Duplicate questions would have the same answers.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Python 3 does *not* expect ASCII from `sys.stdin`. It'll open `stdin` in text mode and make an educated guess as to what encoding is used. That guess may come down to `ASCII`, but that is not a given. See the [`sys.stdin` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) on how the codec is selected.

Like other file objects opened in text mode, the `sys.stdin` object derives from the [`io.TextIOBase` base class](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase); it has a `.buffer` attribute pointing to the underlying buffered IO instance (which in turn has a `.raw` attribute).

Wrap the `sys.stdin.buffer` attribute in a new [`io.TextIOWrapper()` instance](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) to specify a different encoding:

```
import io
import sys

input_stream = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer, encoding='utf-8')
```

Alternatively, set the [`PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable](http://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) to the desired codec when running python.

From Python 3.7 onwards, you can also [reconfigure the existing `std*` wrappers](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper.reconfigure), provided you do it at the start (before any data has been read):

```
# Python 3.7 and newer
sys.stdin.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: What's the nearest equivalent for python2.6?

Comment: @bukzor: Next option: open the file descriptor directly with `io.open()`; `0` is `stdin`: `io.open(0)` returns a `TextIOWrapper()` object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That works pretty great! Thanks! Whole script: http://paste.pound-python.org/show/xoUPpsfFhtKssXBzLxBd/  Deleting my previous failures.

Comment: you could call `sys.stdin.detach()` instead of `sys.stdin.buffer`. Though a preferable solution is to leave the source code along and to configure the environment instead (locale, PYTHONIOENCODING).

Comment: If I use `io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer, encoding='utf-8')` to read from `stdin` in python 2.7, it syas `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'buffer'`. How can one make reading from `stdin` compatible with both python 2 and 3.

Comment: @IrshadBhat: Did you see [Wrap an open stream with io.TextIOWrapper](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34447623)?

Comment: Is there a way to use `sys.stdin.buffer` in Python2 too?

Comment: @alvas: to read binary? See [Reading binary data from stdin](//stackoverflow.com/q/2850893)

Comment: I'm reading text but would like the code to support Python2 and Python3 without doing if sys version =( Specifically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47425695/how-to-read-inputs-from-stdin-and-enforce-an-encoding

Comment: In order to **only** change the encoding, one should preserve the other stream parameters: `io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer, encoding='utf-8', errors=sys.stdin.errors, newline=sys.stdin.newlines, line_buffering=sys.stdin.line_buffering)` However I haven't found a way to acquire the `write_through` parameter.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: Python 3.7 adds a [`write_through` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper.write_through), and more importantly, lets you [reconfigure the wrapper](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper.reconfigure).

Comment: @Martijn Peters: What happens under your suggestions, if, say, one in 1000 bytes has been somehow corrupted, and causes a local deviation from utf-8?

Comment: @DavidEpstein: that's a rather hypothetical situation. The default error handler is `strict`, so an exception will be raised when you try to read data from stdin that is not proper UTF-8. Set the `errors` option to a different error handler to change that behaviour, but corrupted data is corrupted data.

Comment: @Martin Pieters In articles about utf-8 it is pointed out that an advantage of utf-8 over many other encodings is that it is easy to recover from a rare error in a byte stream. So what you say sounds very useful in some circumstances (depending on the source of the input).

Comment: @DavidEpstein: yes, and [setting an error handler other than `strict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers) will let you skip corrupted bytes until a new valid start byte for a sequence is found. None of which has much to do with this specific answer, that is universally applicable to Python's encoding handling.

Comment: `sys.stdin.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')` gives **AttributeError: 'StdInputFile' object has no attribute 'reconfigure'** in Python 3.9.0

Comment: @Suncatcher: `StdInputFile` is *not a standard library type*. The `reconfigure()` method only exists on the [`io.TextIOWrapper()` class](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper). It appears you are using Python in an IDE or other specialised environment. You'd have that issue in any Python version.

Comment: I import `sys` and putting this line into script and calling this `.py` file in an IDLE based on 3.9.0 like that `exec(open('C:\\script.py').read())` so I believe it is clean-green standard, I am too newbie to use any additional modules or libraries on top of standard Python

Comment: @Suncatcher: IDLE is the IDE here, and has replaced the standard `sys.stdout` object with a custom object. That class is part of the IDLE internal implementation, not a standard library class.

Comment: So when you `reconfigure` it does apply only to the current file?