# Encoding utf-8 error, when stdin is used instead of command line arguments

Tags: python, encoding, stdout, stdin

I need to make my script usable for UNIX commands, in order to make it possible for example to process 2 input files at once with my script. This script works perfectly well with command line arguments:

```
newlist = []
def f1()
 .... 
  return places 
  return persons
  return unknown

def f2(input_file):

  volume_id = sys.argv[3]   

  for line in input_data:  

     if any(place+'</dfn>' in line.decode('utf-8') for place in places):
         line = line.replace('"person"', '"place"')
         line = line.replace('id="', 'id="'+volume_id)
     elif any(unk+'</dfn>' in line.decode('utf-8') for unk in unknown):
         line = line.replace('"person"', '"undefined"')
         line = line.replace('id="', 'id="'+volume_id)
     elif 'class="person"' in line.decode('utf-8') and '<dfn' not in line:
         line = line.replace('class="person"', '')
         line = line.replace('id="', 'id="'+volume_id)
     elif 'id="' in line:
         line = line.replace('id="', 'id="'+volume_id)

     newlist.append(line)

  return  newlist                

def main():
   if len(sys.argv) < 4:
     print 'usage: ./myscript.py [file_in... file_out... volume_id]'
     sys.exit(1)

   else:

    filename = sys.argv[1]
    filename_out = sys.argv[2]

    tree = etree.parse(filename)
    extract(tree)

    input_file = open(filename, 'rU')
    change_class(input_file)

    file_new = open(filename_out, 'w')
    for x in newlist:

      if '\n' in x:                   
         x = x.replace('\n', '')                
      print>>file_new, x
```

When I tried to add stdin stdout to it, I first had a problem with reading the same input file first, and for this reason made some chages so that it would be actually open only once. I modified the following:

```
  def f2(input_data) #instead of input_file
```

and I modified main():

```
        filename = sys.argv[1]
        filename_out = sys.argv[2]

        if filename == '-':
           input_file = sys.stdin

        else:
            input_file = open(filename, 'rU')


        if filename_out == '-':
            filename_out = sys.stdout
            file_new = filename_out
        else:
            file_new = open(filename_out, 'w')

        input_data = input_file.read()

        tree = etree.fromstring(input_data)
        extract(tree)


        change_class(input_data)

        for x in newlist:

            if '\n' in x:                   
               x = x.replace('\n', '')                
            print>>file_new, x
```

I run the program from the command line:
    ./myscript.py - - volumeid < inputfile > outputfile

And now I get an encoding problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./exportXMLstd.py", line 192, in <module>
    main()
  File "./exportXMLstd.py", line 182, in main
    change_class(input_data)
  File "./exportXMLstd.py", line 135, in change_class
    if any(place+'</dfn>' in line.decode('utf-8') for place in places):
  File "./exportXMLstd.py", line 135, in <genexpr>
    if any(place+'</dfn>' in line.decode('utf-8') for place in places):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place; can you please use copy and pasting to put your code in the question, then the `{}` button on the toolbar to format the code if it doesn't have enough indentation yet?

Comment: I second the indentation comment. Also, you seem to be assuming stdin is unicode -- is that true on your system? Actually, if you are processing XML data, wouldn't it be best to either assume utf-8, or at least read the xml declaration statement and parse the encoding there?

Comment: sorry for ugly indentation, I corrected it.
@user590028, are you talking about this # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- at the beginning of the script? If so, then I have it.

Comment: @user590028, I have no idea if stdin is unicode, can I declare it somehow somewhere?

Comment: No...I was referring to the input decoding you are doing. I see you are opening the file open(filename, 'rU'). This will return unicode strings...but you make no such attempt to decode stdin. I assumed you thought stdin was going to give you unicode. I know of no such systems -- but that doesn't mean you are not on such a system.  I recommend you open the file open(filename, 'rb'), and do the encode('utf-8') yourself after each read.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
if filename == '-':
    input_file = sys.stdin

else:
    input_file = open(filename, 'rb')

tree = etree.fromstring(input_file.read())
...
```

I think it's likely the XML source is utf-8 (whether it comes from stdin OR from a file)

Comment: Now I get the error message from lxml module: lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: None

Comment: You get a syntax error invoking etree.fromstring()?  What if you use the python etree.fromstring (import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree)

Comment: but I have already imported etree: from lxml import etree. Anyway, I tried to import as you said - it yields another error: xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0

Comment: Actually, both lxml & xml.etree.ElementTree are reporting syntax errors in your source XML document. Does it include an xml declaration statement? ie: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: actually my input files are html documents, they start with <html><head>..etc directly, without declaration. But I parsed them before, when I used command line arguments, without any problems

Comment: What does line one look like? Specifically line 1, column 0

Comment: <html><head><title>Index</title>

Comment: Insert this before the etree.fromstring(), print '%r' % input_file.read(32). Let's see what that shows

Comment: it yields the same error: ParseError, no element found: line 1, column 0

Comment: The print statement didn't display anything?

Comment: Your file has nothing in it

Comment: it has contents! I also tried to put another html-file as input, but same problems

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47979/discussion-between-user590028-and-elaine-blath)

Comment: same error message. I was wondering, if my problem is not similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549332/python-3-how-to-specify-stdin-encoding  and maybe it is possible to resolve it with io module, changing stdin encoding