# How to use csv.DictReader on a tarfile object in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tarfile

Here's the issue I'm running into:

```
Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

The code that's causing this looks something like:

```
for fileinfo in tarfile.open(filename):
    f = t.extractfile(fileinfo)
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    reader.fieldnames
```

The trouble seems to be that the `extractfile()` method produces a [io.BufferedReader](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tarfile.html) that is a very basic file-like object and has no high-level text interface.

What would be a good way to handle this?

I'm thinking of looking at decoding the bytes from the reader into text but I need to retain streaming because these files are *very* large. The codebase is Python 3.6 running on Docker/Linux.

Comment: I'm too lazy to tar a csv file and post a complete and tested solution, but you should take a look at [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper).

Comment: Can't you just wrap it as a text stream using the [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) module? Something like `codecs.getreader("utf-8")(t.extractfile(fileinfo))`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both @Aran-Fey and @zwer who led me to [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447623/wrap-an-open-stream-with-io-textiowrapper) that answered it. Here's how:

```
for fileinfo in tarfile.open(filename):
    with t.extractfile(fileinfo) as f:
        ft = codecs.getreader("utf-8")(f)
        reader = csv.DictReader(ft)
        reader.fieldnames
```

This seems to work so far.