# Difference between `codecs.StreamReader` and `io.TextIOWrapper`

Tags: python, io, codec

What is the difference between using `codecs.StreamReader` and `io.TextIOWrapper` on a binary stream?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import codecs
import io

stream = io.BytesIO(b'abc')
#reader = codecs.getreader('utf-8')(stream)
reader = io.TextIOWrapper(stream)
print(reader, reader.read())
```

Comment: Why would you create a bytes-like object/stream and then feed it to `TextIOWrapper`?

Comment: @wwii This is just an example. But to answer your question, when someone else gives you a bytes-like stream.

Comment: codecs works in Python 2 and 3? ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/34511829/2823755

Comment: @wwii Python 2 no longer exists.

Comment: No legacy code for you then.

Comment: @wwii Yeah. I have already upgraded.