# Json loading with stdin failure

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file-io, user-input

I am trying to load my json file with the `stdin` using the Windows command line: `python algo.py < number.json` and using `json.loads(sys.stdin)` in my script but it fails.

However, I can load my json with

```
with open('number.json',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
n = json.loads(f)
```

Exception raised when using `json.loads(sys.stdin)`:

`the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper`

Exception raised when using `json.load(sys.stdin) or json.loads(sys.stdin.read())`:

`Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Anyone encountered the same issue? I read multiple posts in this forum prior asking help.

Here is the json file:

```
[
  {
    "x": 1,
    "y": 4,
    "z": -1,
    "t": 2
  },
  {
    "x": 2,
    "y": -1,
    "z": 3,
    "t": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: `json.load(sys.stdin)` (without `s`)

Comment: both `load` and `loads` fails with the `sys.stdin` method.

Comment: What is the error message exactly? `json.load(sys.stdin)` works for me with a proper json file.

Comment: The exception raises that it should be a string, bytes but not a "TextIOWrapper" @KlausD.

Comment: json.load(open('number.json')) will definitely work!

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran I just tried `json.load(open(sys.stdin))` because I need to use sys.stdin and got `expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper` with your suggestion... may you know why?

Comment: @ThePjot see above, please.

Comment: trying to load the content from `sys.stdin` won't work because it's a file-like object so it's expected that you get the first exception you mentioned. The second error points to the data you are getting not being a valid JSON so could you just print what you get from calling to `sys.stdin.read()`. A `print(sys.stdin.read())` will do.

Comment: `ï»¿[
  {
    "x": 1,
    "y": 4,
    "z": -1,
    "t": 2
  },
  {
    "x": 2,
    "y": -1,
    "z": 3,
    "t": 0
  }
]` Here is what I obtained with `print(sys.stdin.read())` @Layo

Comment: What python 3 version are you using exactly? My test was using 3.6.8

Comment: @eliaroseX it's clear that the first 3 chars (`ï»¿`) are causing `json.loads()` to fail. You need to investigate why are those chars on the "string", I'm sorry I can't help you further because I don't run on Windows.

Comment: The three chars are the [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), when interpreted as `latin1` (also known as [ISO/IEC 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)).

Comment: @rtoijala what you’re saying is interesting because there is an optional parameter encoder on the function json.load but it doesn’t help on that case unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, your problem seems to be that you have the [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) prepended to your file. That means that the extra three bytes `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF` are found first in your file.

The Python `json` module [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#character-encodings) says that it does not accept a BOM. Therefore you must remove it before passing the JSON data to `json.load` or `json.loads`.

There are at least three ways to remove the BOM. The best is to simply edit your JSON file to remove it. If that is not possible, you can skip it in your Python code.

If only need your code to work with files that contain a BOM, you can use:

```
assert b'\xEF\xBB\xBF' == sys.stdin.buffer.read(3)
```

This makes sure that the removed bytes were really the UTF-8 BOM.

If you need to work with files that may or may not contain a BOM, you can wrap your standard input stream with a `TextIOWrapper` with the correct encoding, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16549381/11345381). Then the code looks like this:

```
import io
stdin_wrapper = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer, encoding='utf-8-sig')
# use stdin_wrapper instead of stdin
```

Quoting the [Python Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data) for why `utf-8-sig`:

> In some areas, it is also convention to use a “BOM” at the start of UTF-8 encoded files; the name is misleading since UTF-8 is not byte-order dependent. The mark simply announces that the file is encoded in UTF-8. For reading such files, use the ‘utf-8-sig’ codec to automatically skip the mark if present.