# Invalid UTF-8 with sys.stdin.read()

Tags: python, utf-8, stdin, apache-nifi

I have an issue where some of my flow files in NiFi contain invalid UTF-8 encoding. When I attempt to read my flow file into a Python script using the `ExecuteStreamCommand` it produces an error at `sys.stdin.read()` because that assumes UTF-8 encoding. I can't figure out how to coerce the encoding to be UTF-8 when I read it in--I figured out that I can use `string.encode('utf-8').strip().decode('utf-8')` with a string but I'm not quite sure how to apply this to `stdin`.

I attempted

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import json
import re
import sys
import io

try:
    flow_file = sys.stdin.read()
    sys.stdout.write(str(flow_file))
except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
    flow_file = sys.stdin.encode('utf-8').strip().decode('utf-8')
    sys.stdout.write(str(flow_file))
```

but it failed

```
  File "/path/to/scripts/test_encoding.py", line 12, in <module>
    flow_file = sys.stdin.encode('utf-8').strip().decode('utf-8')
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549332/python-3-how-to-specify-stdin-encoding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3: How to specify stdin encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549332/python-3-how-to-specify-stdin-encoding)

Comment: @daggett I did see that and, unfortunately, I'm not totally clear on how it could work. I tried `sys.stdin.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')` and it said `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'reconfigure'`. As for using `io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer, encoding='utf-8')` I'm not totally clear on how to coerce it to be utf-8 and write out a flow file with proper utf-8 encoding.